# System.Web.Script.Serialization cannot be solved using Visual Studios 2017

Tags: json, vb.net

I have tried looking at the similar Stack Overflow questions that are similar to mine, but none of those solutions seem to be helping my problem. So I am asking again.

I changed the Project properties to .NET Framework 4, after doing some research online people had been saying that was a better Framework. Originally, I had been using .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I tried the MSDN webpage and incorporating the namespace and assembly, but I would just get more errors.

My error is:

> Error BC30002 Type 'JavaScriptSerializer' is not
>   defined.  VB_to_JSON_One  C:\Users\cmannar\source\repos\VB_to_JSON_One\VB_to_JSON_One\Module1.vb  8   Active

And my warning is:

> Warning   BC40056 Namespace or type specified in the Imports
>   'System.Web.Script.Serialization' doesn't contain any public member or
>   cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and
>   contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element
>   name doesn't use any
>   aliases.  VB_to_JSON_One  C:\Users\cmannar\source\repos\VB_to_JSON_One\VB_to_JSON_One\Module1.vb  2   Active

I am using Visual Studios 2017 and am trying to convert .NET to JSON as shown in the following code:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization ' Sytem.web.extensions.dll
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Public serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()

    Sub Main()

        Dim fileData() As String = File.ReadAllText("JSON_Data.txt").Split(vbLf)
        Dim datapoints As New List(Of DataPoint)

        For Each jsonData As String In fileData
            If jsonData.Trim() <> "" Then datapoints.AddRange(getDeserialisedChargeHRData(jsonData))
        Next

        Dim sortedDataPoints As List(Of DataPoint) = datapoints.OrderBy(Function(o) o.dateTime).ToList()

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.AppendLine("Date and time,BPM,Confidence,Calories burned,Default zone,Custom zone")

        For Each dp As DataPoint In datapoints
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},""{4}"",""{5}""", dp.dateTime, dp.bpm, dp.confidence, dp.caloriesBurned, dp.defaultZone, dp.customZone))
        Next

        File.WriteAllText("BMP_Data.csv", sb.ToString())

    End Sub

    Public Function getDeserialisedChargeHRData(ByVal json As String) As List(Of DataPoint)
        Dim deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of RootObject))(json)
        Return deserializedResult.Item(0).dataSets.activity.dataPoints
    End Function

End Module

Public Class DataPoint
    Public Property bpm() As Integer
    Public Property confidence() As Integer
    Public Property caloriesBurned() As Double
    Public Property defaultZone() As String
    Public Property customZone() As String
    Public Property dateTime() As Date
End Class

Public Class Activity
    Public Property dataPoints() As List(Of DataPoint)
    Public Property granularity() As String
End Class

Public Class DataSets
    Public Property activity() As Activity
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property dataSets() As DataSets
End Class
```

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to describe the actual problem you're encountering...

Comment: Okay I included the exact warning and error @David

Comment: I suggest that you put the framework version back to 4.6.1 and get it working again. Then you can start a new project in 4.0 and copy-and-paste the code into it. Also, consider if the people (who you forgot to cite) suggesting 4.0 is better than 4.6.1 might not have had your code in mind.

Comment: @AndrewMorton at this link is where I found information to change my framework version. It was the answer given by  Harry Zhu:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0710131c-2b7a-4531-bc34-7cceab44d93e/cant-reference-systemwebextensions?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: I mean even when I was originally using the 4.6.1 I was still receiving problems. I had the exact same warning and error that I posted above.

Comment: Note that the very first words in the MSDN documentation for for`JavaScriptSerializer` is *`Json.NET should be used serialization and deserialization`*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import \`Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605048/cannot-import-imports-system-web-script-serialization)

Comment: @Candy 1) FYI, Harry Zhu is a mod on that forum, and the mods often mark answers which worked, to keep things tidy, when the OP doesn't do so. 2) Either [Cannot import `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15605048/1115360) or what Plutonix pointed out should work.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm sorry.. could you elaborate a little more? I don't fully understand how to implement what you said

Comment: JSON.NET is a very good 3rd Party, all purpose JSON serializer/deserializer. There are hundreds of posts here on using it, but it is very easy to learn/use.  If you combined it with CSVHelper you could process those files without your code touching the data at all

Comment: @AndrewMorton I already tried what that Stack Overflow suggested and it did not help me. That is why I said I was re-posting this. I need to know if anyone has any other suggestions for how to solve this

Comment: I got it working! Thanks @Plutonix